# Add Visitor into Contact List

Tags: exm, contact-facets, marketing-automation

For hands-on on Sitecore Automation tool,
I have crated a Simple Automated campaign   i.e if Logged-in user visited to specific page then goal will be trigger and If goal trigger then add user to contact list and send an email.

But **neighter** user is adding in contact list **nor** mail is going to logged-in user.

Do I need to enable any config setting ,exm setting ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After Performing below steps I am able to see the users in Contact List

https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/12891/1338