# No user inside "Experience Profile" in Sitecore 9

Tags: xdb, experience-profile

In Development environment , While clicking on   XProfile icon , there is no user inside "Experience Profile", I am browsing website locally with loggedin/non- loggedin user but Still no record are listed in XProfile.
[image]

Connection String values are as below, do I need to update any setting ?

I was referring article for rebuild the Reporting DB  , but unable to get
"DACPAC file for the Sitecore_Analytics database " into my dev m/c
https://www.bugdebugzone.com/2016/07/error-connection-string-used-by.html
"https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/reporting/rebuild-reporting.html"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<connectionStrings>
  <!-- 
    Sitecore connection strings.
    All database connections for Sitecore are configured here.
  -->
  <add name="core" connectionString="Data Source=LHHGENZYME01\SA;Initial Catalog=xp0_Core;User ID=sa;Password=***@12" />
  <add name="master" connectionString="Data Source=LHHGENZYME01\SA;Initial Catalog=xp0_Master;User ID=sa;Password=***@12" />
  <add name="web" connectionString="Data Source=LHHGENZYME01\SA;Initial Catalog=xp0_Web;User ID=sa;Password=***@12" />
  <add name="messaging" connectionString="Data Source=LHHGENZYME01\SA;Initial Catalog=xp0_Messaging;User ID=sa;Password=***@12" />
  <add name="xconnect.collection" connectionString="https://xp0.xconnect" />
  <add name="xconnect.collection.certificate" connectionString="StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=024434323BA04210EFCB7E302B5B310D003D8813" />
  <add name="xdb.referencedata" connectionString="Data Source=LHHGENZYME01\SA;Initial Catalog=xp0_ReferenceData;User ID=sa;Password=***@12" />
  <add name="xdb.referencedata.client" connectionString="https://xp0.xconnect" />
  <add name="xdb.referencedata.client.certificate" connectionString="StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=024434323BA04210EFCB7E302B5B310D003D8813" />
  <add name="xdb.processing.pools" connectionString="Data Source=LHHGENZYME01\SA;Initial Catalog=xp0_Processing.Pools;User ID=sa;Password=***@12" />

  <add name="xdb.processing.tasks" connectionString="Data Source=LHHGENZYME01\SA;Initial Catalog=xp0_Processing.Tasks;User ID=sa;Password=***@12" />
  <add name="xdb.marketingautomation" connectionString="Data Source=LHHGENZYME01\SA;Initial Catalog=xp0_MarketingAutomation;User ID=sa;Password=***@12" />
  <add name="xdb.marketingautomation.reporting.client" connectionString="https://xp0.xconnect" />
  <add name="xdb.marketingautomation.reporting.client.certificate" connectionString="StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=024434323BA04210EFCB7E302B5B310D003D8813" />
  <add name="xdb.marketingautomation.operations.client" connectionString="https://xp0.xconnect" />
  <add name="xdb.marketingautomation.operations.client.certificate" connectionString="StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=024434323BA04210EFCB7E302B5B310D003D8813" />
  <add name="experienceforms" connectionString="Data Source=LHHGENZYME01\SA;Initial Catalog=xp0_ExperienceForms;User ID=sa;Password=***@12" />
  <add name="exm.master" connectionString="Data Source=LHHGENZYME01\SA;Initial Catalog=xp0_EXM.Master;User ID=sa;Password=***@12" />
  <add name="EXM.CryptographicKey" connectionString="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />
  <add name="EXM.AuthenticationKey" connectionString="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000" />

  <add name="reporting" connectionString="Data Source=LHHGENZYME01\SA;Initial Catalog=xp0_Reporting;User ID=sa;Password=***@12" />
  <!-- <add name="analytics" connectionString="mongodb://localhost/analytics"/> -->
  <!-- <add name="reporting.secondary" connectionString="Data Source=LHHGENZYME01\SA;Initial Catalog=Sitecore_ Analytics_Secondary;User ID=sa;Password=***@12"/> -->
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Do you have indexing of anonymous contacts enabled? https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-search-indexer/enable-anonymous-contact-indexing.html

Answer (score 6):

1. Set **IndexAnonymousContactData** to true  in **sc.XConnect.IndexerSettings.xml** inside xconnect website in wwwroot

Ref:-
  https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/xp/xconnect/xconnect-search-indexer/enable-anonymous-contact-indexing.html

2.Check below service is running 
  [image]

3.Rebuild the xDB search index

Right Click on service Property "Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - xp0.xconnect-IndexWorker" and get the path

or   go to =>>
wwwroot\xp0.xconnect\App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\
 and open the Command Prompt in admin mode and run **XConnectSearchIndexer -rr**

[image]

Comment: Great post. Worked like a charm.